# Adding Overflow option in Relative Layout in android

Tags: android

I had a Relative Layout, with 5 buttons in the bottom of the screen in 1 row having linear layout. Now i want to add 2 more option, so that it will appear in same way as Action bar Overflow menu.

Is it possible to implement options in Overflow (Like action bar overflow menu) in Linear or Relative layout in Android??

I want to do changes in existing Layout with some buttons, there is no action bar here..

Answer (score 0):

The overflow menu is for when items in the actionbar won't fit on a certain screen size, or to be used as a menu for options are irrelevant being shown in the actionbar. Check here for actionbar docs, and scroll down to the action items.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html